# Google Play app seems corrupted

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have a Samsung Galaxy Skyrocket SII (yes, quite old now) and it's had a litany of issues as of late, but the one I find curious of all is the issue with my Google Play app. Every bit of text within the app (and the actual name of the app underneath the icon) has a bizarre use of accent marks over all the letters in the title, within brackets, and ends with the words, "one two." Installing something from the store is impossible as it always says that there's insufficient space for them, but that's inaccurate. I'm not sure how this affects my phone beyond the program, itself, but I'd be interested to hear if this is something I can repair or if it is the act of something malicious. Thank you.